# Async Method called 2 times in same time

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, task

here's my concern. I have two datePickers that sometimes have to be triggered at the same time (I select an agent, I get its start date and its end date).

I have a method that will retrieve the plannings according to the dates, the problem is that it takes at the same time the start date + the end date + the normal trigger (when I select an agent, its default schedule appears.)
So the result gives me several informations at the same time (I get an error message "no planning" + a planning behind, which doesn't make any sense)

Here is the code:

```
        <DatePicker Grid.Column="1" Name="DatePickerStart"
                            Grid.Row="5"
                            Margin="40,5"
                            Height="25"
                            DisplayDateEnd="{Binding DateEnd}"
                            SelectedDate="{Binding DateStart}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedDateChanged">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LoadMatrice}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedDate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DatePicker}}}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </DatePicker>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="4"
                            Grid.Column="2" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                            VerticalAlignment="Center"
                            FontSize="16"
                            Text="Date Fin:"/>
    <DatePicker Grid.Column="2" Name="DatePickerEnd"
                            Grid.Row="5"
                            Margin="40,5"
                            Height="25"
                            DisplayDateStart="{Binding DateStart}"
                            SelectedDate="{Binding DateEnd}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="SelectedDateChanged">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding LoadMatrice}" CommandParameter="{Binding SelectedDate, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DatePicker}}}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </DatePicker>
```

VM :

```
        private DateTime _DateDebut;
    public DateTime DateDebut
    {
        get
        {
            return _DateDebut;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _DateDebut)
            {
                _DateDebut = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(DateDebut));
            }
        }
    }

    private DateTime _DateFin;
    public DateTime DateFin
    {
        get
        {
            return _DateFin;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _DateFin)
            {
                _DateFin = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(DateFin));
            }
        }
    }
```

When i choose something in my combobox :

```
        private string _SelectedResultList;
    public string SelectedResultList
    {
        get
        {
            return _SelectedResultList;
        }
        set
        {
            if (value != _SelectedResultList)
            {
                _SelectedResultList = value;

                //GetIdSelectedResultList();
                foreach (var periode in PeriodesModulation)
                {

                    if (value == valueILookingFor)
                    {
                        DateStart = periode.Start;
                        DateEnd = periode.End;
                    }
                }
                RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedResultList));
            }
        }
    }
```

The method that is triggered :

```
            LoadMatrice = new RelayCommand(async () =>
        {
            await GetParametresMatrice();
        });
```

and :

```
        public async Task GetParametresMatrice()
    {
        ErrorMatrice = null;

        if (_SelectedChoiceList != null) // important pour ne pas rechercher avec les dates.today du reset avant qu'on ai fait la demande
        {
            GetMatricule(matriculeSelectedAgent);
            Planning = new ObservableCollection<Planning>(await _dataService.GetPlanning(matriculeSelectedAgent, _dataService.ParamGlobaux.IDEtablissement, DateStart, DateEnd));
            GetIdMatrice(Planning);
            Matrice = new ObservableCollection<Matrix>(await _dataService.GetMatrice(idMatrice));
        }
    }
```

I count the number of planning found and :

```
        private void GetIdMatrice(ObservableCollection<Planning> planning)
    {
        idMatrice = null;

        if (planning.Count > 0)
        {
            if (planning.Any(p => p.IDMatrice == null))
            {
                ErrorMatrice = $"Pas de matrice trouvées, modification impossible";
            }
            else if (planning.GroupBy(p => p.IDMatrice).Count() > 1)
            {
                ErrorMatrice = $"Deux matrices différentes trouvées, modification impossible";
            }
            else
            {
                idMatrice = planning.First().IDMatrice;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            ErrorMatrice = $"Pas de planning trouvé sur cette période.";
        }
    }
```

The latter, GetParametresMatrice(), is repeated several times, which is normal, but at the same time, which is problematic. I would like the loops to be done one after the other.

Once the first "loading" has passed, everything is ok. If I change the start date, or the end date, the schedule adjusts. It's really only when I choose a planning and both dates are loaded.

Edit : no problem during the layout loading, because "if (_SelectedChoiceList != null) " line. 
It's my combobox, so that's perfect. 
the problem is when I choose an agent in a combobox and the StartDate / EndDate change at the same time.

EDIT 2 :

[image: end]

When I display the result, I have a schedule + an error message. Which is normally impossible, Planning.count cannot be > 1 AND < 1

Any tips?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you set the `EndDate` in the setter of the `StartDate` which triggers another command or what exactly is your issue?

Comment: My problem is that when I select a combobox A, my start date and end date change at the same time. My code processes them at the same time, not one after the other. So I get inconsistent results. So I'm looking for a way to say to my code "hey, first process the start date, then the end date"

Comment: Then you need to await the async method or the command itself. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main issue seems to be that your `ICommand` implementation (`RelayCommand`) isn't async or awaitable. It if was, you could have awaited the `LoadMatrice` command.

You'll find an example of an async `ICommand` implementation [here](https://johnthiriet.com/mvvm-going-async-with-async-command/#).

```
public class AsyncCommand : IAsyncCommand
{
    public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

    private bool _isExecuting;
    private readonly Func<Task> _execute;
    private readonly Func<bool> _canExecute;
    private readonly IErrorHandler _errorHandler;

    public AsyncCommand(
        Func<Task> execute,
        Func<bool> canExecute = null,
        IErrorHandler errorHandler = null)
    {
        _execute = execute;
        _canExecute = canExecute;
        _errorHandler = errorHandler;
    }

    public bool CanExecute()
    {
        return !_isExecuting && (_canExecute?.Invoke() ?? true);
    }

    public async Task ExecuteAsync()
    {
        if (CanExecute())
        {
            try
            {
                _isExecuting = true;
                await _execute();
            }
            finally
            {
                _isExecuting = false;
            }
        }

        RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }

    public void RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
    {
        CanExecuteChanged?.Invoke(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }

    #region Explicit implementations
    bool ICommand.CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        return CanExecute();
    }

    void ICommand.Execute(object parameter)
    {
        ExecuteAsync().FireAndForgetSafeAsync(_errorHandler);
    }
    #endregion
}
```

You may also want to read [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn630647.aspx) article.

But even if you change type of your command to `AsyncCommand` , the `InvokeCommandAction` that you define in your XAML still won't call the `ExecuteAsync()` method. You'd better call it yourself, or call the async method directly, in your view model. You could for example do this by hooking up an async event handler for the `PropertyChanged` event:

```
public ViewModel()
{
    this.PropertyChanged += async (s, e) =>
    {
        switch (e.PropertyName)
        {
            case nameof(DateDebut):
                await GetParametresMatrice();
                //here the method has completed and you can do whatever you want...
                break;
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: A great answer while I was editing my message. 
I don't understand everything yet - I discover this during my internship - but I will try to understand your answer and find out about it, thank you for your complete answer. And read thoses articles. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Your event triggered twice due to binding DateEnd data and DateStart during load your page layout. Also when you set new data model it  triggers events twice too by the same reason.

You could relocate your logic for allowing execution to command method

```
 public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
    {
        MainWindowViewModel viewModel = parameter as MainWindowViewModel;
        if (viewModel.isNeedToCheck && viewModel.IsWholeModelSet)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: Yeah exactly, but i don't know how to fix it. I need 3 step for update my "Planning" : When dateStart change, when dateEnd change and when i choose a guy in my combobox (and that last point is the problem, cause he change dateStart and DateEnd in same time.)

Comment: You could disable triggering LoadMatrice command from form in case agent selection and execute LoadMatrice command manually. Also you could use command  feature CanExecute and replace allowing to execution logic their